# Connect to remote sql database using SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, vb.net

I finished a program using VB.NET 2008 AND SQL SERVER 2005 AND Linq To SQL. I want to use the program in 2 or More PCs and get access to one Database

I'm using this connection string:

```
db = New connectionString("server=192.168.1.3;database=DBNAME;user=DBUSER;password=DBPASS;integrated security=true")
```

The problem here is I get this message:

> Expiration of the waiting period. The waiting time has elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

NB: The message I got is translated from French language to English..

Comment: You need to have the database server installed on the machine with IP=192.168.1.3, setup the correct protocol on that machine (TCP/IP should be enabled) and the firewall should allow calls on the Sql Server port (usually 1433) and don't forget to create the appropriate user

Comment: I already did what you said.. I setup the IP and the TCP/IP and enabled the firewall to allow calls from SQL SERVER but still the same problem

Comment: If you want to use the User ID and password provided then change the integrated security to SSPI (By the way, the key should be `User ID=....`)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs usually because of two issues,

1 - SQL server unreachable ( due to TCP/IP problems or Firewall problems like steve mentioned above)

2 - Badly written queries that are taking too long and the SQL time expires, in this case kindly see the blow link

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/how-to-identify-slow-running-queries-with-sql-profiler/